# How can I skip mounted directories with chmod?

Tags: freebsd, chmod

`chown` supports a `-x` option to ignore file system mount points. Is there an equivalent for `chmod`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in option. You can use `find` with the `-xdev` option to achieve the same:

```
find /dir -xdev -exec chmod u+rwx {} +
```

Comment: `-xdev` flag doesn't seem to actually work in FreeBSD. Still followed my mounted folder. Same with `chown -x` actually. I found another way by explicitly pruning the folder with `find`. Thanks anyway :-)